# How to simulate sculpt layers in Blender?

Tags: sculpting

I'm wondering if there is a way to sculpt some details on top of existing, already sculpted details, and then change the opacity of newly sculpted details? For example skin pores on top of a wrinkles geometry.

It's like working with layers, where you put a layer on top of the layer underneath and then set the opacity individually for each layer. This apporach is used eg. in Mudbox, please take a look at the following tutorial on 8:20 mark:

https://youtu.be/fh0mZcblVJ4?t=503

Does Blender support that approach or is there a clever way to simulate it?

Comment: It could be possible to simulate that with texture painting bump maps (on several images effect of which can be temporarily disabled). This will be only faking effect though because you won't create any real geometry.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the Sculpt settings in the Multires Motifier in that way. I generally just do all my sculpts on one layer but setting up multiples in this way may do the trick. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please make a more detailed explaination?

Answer (score 1):

There is Sculpt Layers addon https://blenderartists.org/t/sculpt-layers-addon/1288145 .

Answer (score 0):

You can Use shapekeys for similar effect but it's VERY heavy on the blender to do sculpting with.

Comment: Like why is it?

Comment: I don't know but try it yourself on one of your sculpts. brush strokes and updates are infested with lags.